# Windows環境でのSymfony2でCompassのエラー"Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory"

Tags: ruby, symfony2, sass

普段はLinux環境で作業しているのですが、
Windows環境にSymfony2環境を構築する必要があります。

WindowsにXAMPPパッケージをインストールして、
Symfony2フレームワークを設定しました。

システムは問題なく設定・動作しましたが、
Compassの設定でエラーが出ており、問題の原因がわかっておりません。

***config.yml:***

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../../html/
    #bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite  : ~
        sass        :
            bin: "C:\Ruby\bin\sass"
        compass     :
            bin: "C:\Ruby\bin\compass"
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar"
        closure:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
```

***error message:***

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
"C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.EXE" "C:\Ruby\bin\compass" "compile" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp" "--boring" "--config" "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ass1047.tmp" "--sass-dir" "" "--css-dir" "" "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/ass1048.tmp.sass"

Error Output:
Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory.
```

"Individual stylesheets must be in the sass directory."の部分のエラーが理解できておりません。
Compass個別で使用・動作するのは問題ありません。
Symfony2内での設定方法が理解できていない状態です。
Compass & Sass のパス設定以外、同じ設定でLinux環境ではCompassも動作しております。

> 環境

```
Windows : 7
Ruby : 2.1.5
Sass : 3.4.10
Compass : 1.0.3
```

Comment: 解決されたようですが、AsseticおよびCompassの方へissueが挙がっているようでしたのでメモしておきます https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/697  https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1769

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。とりあえず応急処置といったところでしょうか・・・。

Comment: そんな感じですね。ちなみに念のためですがLinuxで動いているという方のcompassのバージョンはいくつだったのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

下記ファイルを編集する
kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/CompassFilter.php

312行目付近

```
$pb->add('--sass-dir')->add('')->add('--css-dir')->add('');
```

to

```
$pb->add('--sass-dir')->add($tempDir)->add('--css-dir')->add($tempDir);
```

`yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar` を `yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar` に変更。

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../../html/
    #bundles:        [ ]
    java: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe
    ruby: C:\Ruby\bin\ruby.exe
    filters:
        cssrewrite  : ~
        sass        :
            bin: C:\Ruby\bin\sass
        compass     :
            bin: C:\Ruby\bin\compass
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
        yui_css:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

一応これで動きました。